# Adjusting QML RowLayout attached properties

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am attempting a simple `RowLayout` of Rectangles. (See code below.) When I attempt to compile/run this in Qt Creator, I get:

`qrc:/main.qml:31 Do not create objects of type Layout`

when I attempt to use either `Layout.minimumWidth:200` or `Layout { minimumWidth:200 }`

The Qt [documentation for `RowLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-rowlayout.html#details) shows the first form working. What am I missing?

```qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "RB3Jay"
    width:1280; height:960
    minimumWidth:600; minimumHeight:300
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: pseudocontent
        height: parent.height - (header.height + footer.height)
        color:'orange'
        anchors {
          top:header.bottom
          bottom:footer.top
          left:parent.left
          right:parent.right
        }
    }

    header: RowLayout {
        id: header
        spacing: 0
        height: 100
        width: parent.width
        Rectangle {
            color:'red'
            Layout {
                minimumWidth:200; maximumWidth:200; preferredWidth:200
                fillHeight:true
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            color:'green'
            Layout {
                minimumWidth: 200
                preferredWidth: parent.width*0.7
                fillWidth:true; fillHeight:true
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            color:'blue'
            Layout {
                minimumWidth: 200
                preferredWidth: parent.width*0.3
                fillWidth:true; fillHeight:true
            }
        }
    }

    footer: Inspector {
        id: footer
        height:100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `foo { bar: 1; baz: 2 }` -syntax works for [grouped properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#grouped-properties), `Foo { }` is reserved for creating an instance of QML type `Foo`. For [attached properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers), you must use the `Foo.bar: 1` -syntax.

[`Layout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) is not a creatable type, it only provides attached properties. Therefore you must use the `Foo.bar: 1` -syntax.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "RB3Jay"
    width:1280; height:960
    minimumWidth:600; minimumHeight:300
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: pseudocontent
        height: parent.height - (header.height + footer.height)
        color:'orange'
        anchors {
          top:header.bottom
          bottom:footer.top
          left:parent.left
          right:parent.right
        }
    }

    header: RowLayout {
        id: header
        spacing: 0
        height: 100
        width: parent.width
        Rectangle {
            color:'red'
            Layout.minimumWidth:200
            Layout.maximumWidth:200
            Layout.preferredWidth:200
            Layout.fillHeight:true
        }
        Rectangle {
            color:'green'
            Layout.minimumWidth: 200
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width*0.7
            Layout.fillWidth:true; Layout.fillHeight:true
        }
        Rectangle {
            color:'blue'
            Layout.minimumWidth: 200
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width*0.3
            Layout.fillWidth:true; Layout.fillHeight:true
        }
    }

    footer: Inspector {
        id: footer
        height:100
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I was certain that `Layout.minimumWidth` was throwing the same error, but I must have been mistaken. My question is invalid. Thank you for your help.